# How many times will this loop run, mathematically?

Tags: loops, math, count

```
while ( n > 0 ) {
    n = n/2 ;
}
```

It's a mathematical question.
Every answer is much appreciated.
peace.

Comment: If it's a math question then it's off-topic. But as you asked, it wouldn't run because `n` isn't initialized and is more than likely 0 - so the `while` condition is never met to trigger the loop.

Comment: When don't you try it for some different values of n, and then make a guess? Is n an int, or a float, or a double, or something else?

Comment: Since the operation `n = n / 2` can never change the sign of `n`, the loop will either run not at all or forever, depending on the initial value of `n`. This doesn't really become interesting until you drag programming languages into it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: 1/2 == 0 in C# at least (probably in most languages) so it will eventually terminate.

Comment: @EricJ. though the OP did say 'mathematically'...

Comment: Integer mathematics is a branch of mathematics... and most likely what is actually intended, as this looks like a classic illustration of Big O.

Comment: @EricJ. Hence "this doesn't become interesting until you drag programming languages into it". Languages that can do infinite precision math may also have the loop "terminate", but on an out of memory. I was pointing out why the question isn't interesting when considered purely mathematically. Unless the OP meant "what is the complexity of this", as you seem to have interpreted it. Don't you just love vague, ambiguous questions?

Comment: n is an int and it can be any int. I am searching for a sentence that can provide me with the right loop times for every value of the integer n . foe example if you give n=3 it will run 2 times .

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is an integer, and `/` is the integer division operator where `1 / 2` is `0`, then the loop will do either of two things:

- if `n` is initially <= 0, it will run 0 times.
- if `n` is positive, it will run precisely `floor(log2(n)) + 1` times, where `log2` is the binary logarithm of `n` (`log(n) / log(2)`). This happens to be exactly the same as the number of bits necessary to store `n`, which is not a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

What is `n`?

In my case it is a C++ class something like:

```
class MyN {
public:
    bool operator > (int) const { return true; }
    MyN & operator / (int) { return *this; }
}
```

... so forever.

But if we take `n` to be an integer type that rounds towards 0 then:

- The loop will run zero times if `n` is less than or equal to `0`
- Otherwise the loop will run `floor( log2 n ) + 1` times.

Comment: n is a hypothetical number. it could be 7 or 2 or anything. its a mathematical question, my question is, to find a sentence that works for every integer (n) . so if there was while(n>0) { n--; } this would run n times . thank you

Comment: @user3209681 in which case you question is off topic for stackoverflow. http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be a better venue. You would also do well to specify that `n` is an integer if that is what you actually mean.

Comment: n is an int and it can be any int. I am searching for a sentence that can provide me with the right loop times for every value of the integer n . foe example if you give n=3 it will run 2 times .

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of fictional abstraction (mathematics), it will run forever, but this is not a useful information :)

According to real-objective world,

Xenonesque view: Loop will run until achilles catches the turtle.

Democritusesque view: Loop will run until quantitative changes on object (number -as a mathematical object) will be one step aside the quantitative transformation - transformation of the nature of this object. More changes can not be the perceived by our consciousness, at least in the context of initial object, so it should be better to stop here and to name that last divisible object, atomic number.

CSesque view: Until the interpreter/compiler will evaluate the division to zero.

For python 2.7, when applying below function

```
def steps_to_zero(n, i=0):
    while n>0:
        n = n/2.0
        i+=1
    return i
```

to ranges, (partially from 1 to 10**308), the minimum value is 1075, max 2098. Thus 10 times increase on range can only lift up the iteration 3 times.

Answer (score -2):

If the n is an integer then the loop will run 23 times. Kindly inform me if you need proofs or a working detail.

I tested it in c++ as an integer and that was how I got the 23. It seems like I didn't get the question correctly. below is the code that I used:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
int x = 0;

while ( n > 0 )
{
    cout << n << endl;
    x++;
    n = n/2 ;
}
cout << "Amount of times loop is: " << x << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is a hypothetical number. it could be 7 or 2 or anything. its a mathematical question, my question is, to find a sentence that works for every integer (n) . so if there was while(n>0) { n--; } this would run n times . thank you